# Input data creation for Multilabel classification

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multilabel-classification

I am working on a multilabel classification problem. Every value in X is a categorical value. Original data is below

```
ID  X1  X2  X3  Y
111 AA  LL  KK  MMM
111 AA  LL  KK  MMM
111 BB  LL  jj  NNN
121 HH  DD  uu  III
121 HH  DD  yy  OOO
121 HH  LL  aa  PPP
```

I am trying to convert this to a dataframe where every unique value present in columns (X1, X2, X3, Y) will become a new column and every ID will have a single record. The expected output I am trying to get is

```
ID  X1_AA   X1_BB   X1_HH   X2_LL   X2_DD   X3_KK   X3_jj   X3_uu   X3_yy   x3_aa   Y_MMM   Y_NNN   Y_III   Y_OOO   Y_PPP
111 1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
121 0   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   1
```

I tried using pandas get_dummies, it is creating dummy column, but id's are duplicated. Here Y is my target column. Multiple values of Y for an ID means ID has accessed multiple channels.

**Also please suggest if I can directly use original data by creating dummy columns for X and Y in classification**

Comment: Add input in text format, not in Images.

Comment: `Also please suggest if I can directly use original data by creating dummy columns for X and Y in classification` - can you explain more?

Comment: @ jezrael  Point I am trying to make is by using get_dummies from pandas, without creating single record per ID, and then use this as input for algorithm to predict labels. In this case shape of my new data will be same as original input data. I am not sure if this is the correct approach

Comment: @Lucy - I think this should be new question, the best in [https://stats.stackexchange.com/](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @jezrael I'll post this as a new question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For dummies in output is necessary aggregate `max`:

```
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df).groupby('ID', as_index=False).max()
print (df1)
    ID  X1_AA  X1_BB  X1_HH  X2_DD  X2_LL  X3_KK  X3_aa  X3_jj  X3_uu  X3_yy  \
0  111      1      1      0      0      1      1      0      1      0      0   
1  121      0      0      1      1      1      0      1      0      1      1   

   Y_III  Y_MMM  Y_NNN  Y_OOO  Y_PPP  
0      0      1      1      0      0  
1      1      0      0      1      1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new_df = pd.get_dummies(df).groupby('ID').sum()
new_df[new_df > 1] = 1
```

---

```
ID  X1_AA   X1_BB   X1_HH   X2_DD   X2_LL   X3_KK   X3_aa   X3_jj   X3_uu   X3_yy   Y_III   Y_MMM   Y_NNN   Y_OOO   Y_PPP
111 1   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0
121 0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   1
```

Edit: I wasn't aware of `.max()` method in groupby. @jezrael's answer is definetely a better one.